# Kafka Streams Lost Produced Messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka Streams with Spring Boot and after some aggregations I produce data to a new topic. When I consume records (with kafka-console-consumer) from this topic at the first time all messages present (nearly 52k records). But at the second time this number is very different (32k, 18k or even 10k records).

I use dockerized kafka cluster with 3 nodes and replication factor 3. How can I prevent data lost?

Example of my stream code:

```
KStream<Long, JsonNode> st1 = KafkaUtils.readStream(builder, TOPIC_1, (k, v) -> v.get("id").asLong(), jsonSerde); 
KStream<Long, JsonNode> st2 = KafkaUtils.readStream(builder, TOPIC_2, (k, v) -> v.get("id").asLong(), jsonSerde); 

st2
.join(st1, valueJoiner, JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofHours(1)), StreamJoined.with(Serdes.Long(), jsonSerde, jsonSerde))
.transform(CustomTimestampTransformer<Long>::new) //My custom transformer for extracting timestamps from record 
.to(OUTPUT_TOPIC, Produced.with(Serdes.Long(), jsonSerde));
```

Comment: The console consumer starts from the end of the topic, by default. Try adding `--from-beginning`

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer. I use this flag always and have this problem.

Comment: Can you share you streams code as a [mcve], please

Comment: I assume you've read how the join window duration actually works between streams? I don't think you are losing data; just your events are not falling within the window you expect, based on your timestamp transformer (you should show this class, too)

Comment: May be my example is a little bit confusing for you as you don't know this data and some other internals, I'm sorry for that. But I have concrete problem: when I consume messages with kafka-console-consumer at the first time I have 52k records. But at the second time (with different consumer group id and --from-beginning flag) I have only 32k or records or even less.

Comment: It's entirely possible you are consuming records while they are actively being deleted due to retention, but (eventually) you should get a consistent count

Comment: How can I prevent this deleting?

Comment: All I'm saying is that it's possible. That's just a feature of Kafka, by default, it only holds data for a week. If your topic is brand new, then that's not the case. Without more details about how much data you're producing, or even logs from the broker, I'm just guessing. I will say that you don't need 3 brokers on one machine, containers or not